# New to Oracle, typing to retrieve data from two sets, compare and conditionally insert

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm trying to build a query to grab all rows from Table 1, then check if a corresponding row exists in Table 2, and if so, pull some data, JOIN and insert into Table 3. This will make more sense in pseudocode - so here's what I'm trying to do, procedurally, I'm just not sure how to implement this in PL/SQL.

```
For all rows in T1:
    For all rows in T2:
        if (T1.mycolumn - T2.othercolumn) > 0:
            INSERT INTO T3 (foo, bar) VALUES T1.foo, T2.bar
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are describing something like

```
INSERT INTO t3( foo, bar )
  SELECT t1.foo,
         t2.bar
    FROM t1
         LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON (t1.mycolumn > t2.othercolumn)
```

I'm not sure that's actually what you want, though.  Some sample data and the expected output would be helpful.  In what you're describing, `t1.foo` values may get inserted many times into `t3` because they match many different rows in `t2`.  Normally, there would be some sort of key that is common to `t1` and `t2` that you would use to determine whether an appropriate `t2` row exists and the `t1.mycolumn > t2.otherColumn` condition would just be another predicate

```
INSERT INTO t3( foo, bar )
  SELECT t1.foo,
         t2.bar
    FROM t1
         LEFT OUTER JOIN t2 ON (    t1.someKey = t2.someKey 
                                AND t1.mycolumn > t2.othercolumn)
```

Comment: I think the latter query is exactly what I was looking for. I will give it a try and see what happens. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into T3 (foo, bar)
select T1.foo, T2.bar
from T1, T2
where T1.mycolumn - T2.othercolumn > 0
```